# DPDK : Complication issue on Ubuntu 22.04 ( dpdk-21.11 )

Tags: ubuntu, intel, dpdk

I am getting missing dependency for following drivers in Ubuntu 22.04 (dpdk-21.11).

```
drivers:
        common/mvep:    missing dependency, "libmusdk"
        net/af_xdp:     missing dependency, "libbpf"
        net/mvneta:     missing dependency, "libmusdk"
        net/mvpp2:      missing dependency, "libmusdk"
        net/nfb:        missing dependency, "libnfb"
        raw/ioat:       replaced by dmadev drivers
        crypto/armv8:   missing dependency, "libAArch64crypto"
        crypto/mvsam:   missing dependency, "libmusdk"

Build targets in project: 1039
NOTICE: Future-deprecated features used:
 * 0.56.0: {'meson.build_root', 'meson.source_root'}

Found ninja-1.10.1 at /usr/bin/ninja
root@pallav-virtual-machine:~/dpdk-21.11#
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

We need to compile following git repository

crypto/mvsam:   missing dependency, "libmusdk"

https://github.com/MarvellEmbeddedProcessors/musdk-marvell

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).